# Modifying array elements with inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Is there a way of modifying specific array elements with inline assembly ?

```
int move[2];
```

I'm looking to change `move[0]` and `move[1]` in `__asm`.
I am a novice with assembly coding, mainly stick to C++, and there is probably a very simple answer.
So far I've attempted to move `move[1]` into registers, move the number I want to change it to into another, and then move one into the other. I have managed to get it to compile but it doesnt actually work.

Comment: What is the motivation for using assembly for this ? Is it just homework or curiosity or what ?

Comment: Optimisation assignment, I want to use assembly in parts of it but I've become stuck on this.

Comment: Assembly is the last resort for optimisation - there are probably much easier and more effective things you can do before trying to outsmart the compiler. But if the assignment requires assembly then all I can say is good luck!

Comment: Hey, I'm impressed it can compile. And run. haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like `MOV array[TYPE array * index], value;`, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};

  printf("%d\n", foo[0]);
  printf("%d\n", foo[1]);
  printf("%d\n", foo[2]);

  __asm {
    MOV foo[TYPE foo * 0], 11;
    MOV foo[TYPE foo * 1], 22;
    MOV foo[TYPE foo * 2], 33;
  };

  printf("%d\n", foo[0]);
  printf("%d\n", foo[1]);
  printf("%d\n", foo[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

`TYPE` will return the size of one element of the array. The output:

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
```

Comment: Cheers! But for some reason I'm now getting an error 'label 'array' was undefined'...

Comment: `array` is the name of the variable `array`, change it with yours, maybe `move`.

Comment: mov move[type array * 0], 0;
mov move[type array * 1], -1;
like that?

Comment: @user3169641 No like this `mov move[type move * 0], 0; mov move[type move * 1], -1`, the only hardcoded words are the once in capital.