# Inline asm and c array questions

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

This is a homework. I have 3 arrays, v1={5,4,3,2,1} ,v2={1,2,3,4,5} and v3={2,3,5,1,4}, the assigment is to change the 1 to 6. Of course, any solution like v1[4]=6, in asm or c is forbidden. So this was my code:

**First Code**

```
void main(){
int myArray[5]={5,4,3,2,1};

__asm {
    mov ecx,0 //using ecx as counter
myLoop: 
    mov eax, myArray[ecx] //moving the content on myArray in position ecx to eax
    cmp eax,1            //comparing eax to 1
    je is_one            //if its equal jump to label is_one
    inc ecx              //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5     //since all vectors have size 5, comparing if ecx is equal to 5
    jne myLoop          //if not, repeat
    jmp Done            //if true, go to label Done
is_one: 
    mov myArray[ecx],6 //changing the content in myArray position ecx to 6
    inc ecx            //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5          // ecx=5?
    jne myLoop         //no? repeat loop
    jmp Done           //yes? Done
Done:
    }
printArray(myArray);
}
```

this didn't work, tried many things like `mov eax,6` or `mov [eax+ecx],6` , nothing worked until I found **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369405/modifying-array-elements-with-inline-assembly)**

**Many tries later code**

```
void main(){
int myArray[5]={5,4,3,2,1};

__asm {
    mov ecx,0 //using ecx as counter
myLoop: 
    mov eax, myArray[TYPE myArray*ecx] //I don't understand how this works
    cmp eax,1            //comparing eax to 1
    je is_one            //if its equal jump to label is_one
    inc ecx              //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5     //since all vectors have size 5, comparing if ecx is equal to 5
    jne myLoop          //if not, repeat
    jmp Done            //if true, go to label Done
is_one: 
    mov myArray[TYPE myArray*ecx],6 //Uhh...
    inc ecx            //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5          // ecx=5?
    jne myLoop         //no? repeat loop
    jmp Done           //yes? Done
Done:
    }
printArray(myArray);
}
```

And that works like a charm. But I don't understand how or why the `MOV array[TYPE array * index], value` works(besides TYPE returning the size as explained in link), and why not the others.

Also, since I have to do this for 3 arrays, I tried to copy and paste all the code to `changingArray(int myArray[])`, declared the 3 arrays in the main, and passed them to changingArray, but now is not changing them. Im pretty sure that with vector you dont have to pass with &, I could be wrong. Still, I can't see why it doesn't change them. So...

**Final Code**

```
void changingArray(int myArray[]){
__asm {
    mov ecx,0 //using ecx as counter
myLoop: 
    mov eax, myArray[TYPE myArray*ecx] //I don't understand how this works
    cmp eax,1            //comparing eax to 1
    je is_one            //if its equal jump to label is_one
    inc ecx              //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5     //since all vectors have size 5, comparing if ecx is equal to 5
    jne myLoop          //if not, repeat
    jmp Done            //if true, go to label Done
is_one: 
    mov myArray[TYPE myArray*ecx],6 //Uhh...
    inc ecx            //ecx+1
    cmp ecx,5          // ecx=5?
    jne myLoop         //no? repeat loop
    jmp Done           //yes? Done
Done:
    }
printArray(myArray);
}

void main(){
   //for some odd reason, they arent changing
   int v1[5]={5,4,3,2,1}; 
   int v2[5]={1,2,3,4,5};  
   int v3[5]={2,3,5,1,4};
   changingArray(v1);
   changingArray(v2);
   changingArray(v3);
}
```

**TL:DR section**:

Homework of changing the number 1 to 6 in 3 arrays v1={5,4,3,2,1} ,v2={1,2,3,4,5} and v3={2,3,5,1,4}

1-I don't get why the first code doesn't work, but many tries later code works (the `MOV array[TYPE array * index], value` instruction).

2- Since I need to do this with 3 arrays, I put all the code in `changingArray(int myArray[])`, and in the main I declared my 3 arrays in main as shown in final code. While many tries code did change the array, this doesnt. Probably I just made a mistake in c and not asm, but I don't see it.

And sorry for bad english, is not my first language.

Comment: `int` takes up 4 bytes. Without `TYPE myarray`, you're indexing by bytes, not multiplying by the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov eax, myArray[TYPE myArray*ecx]
```

Here the address referred to is (base address of myArray) + sizeof(the type of elements of myArray) * ecx. In assembly language the indexing should be done in bytes.