# Assembly inline in c

Tags: c, nasm

I have read tons of similar questions about this stuff here but still can't solve my problem.
I need to use this piece of assembly code in C file:

```
unsigned char * led = (char *) 0xC0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  __asm
    {
      ror [led[i]],1
    };    
}
```

I just need to rotate all values in `led` variable by 1 bit. While using this code I get an `Factor expected` error. When i remove `[]` brackets around `led` value, it is `end of line expected` error.
Strange thing is the code bellow works perfectly:

```
  __asm
    {
      nop
    };
```

As you can see these samples look very similar but there is only one working properly. What am I doing wrong?
If it is relevant i try to make an easy application in CodeWarrior, which is IDE for embedded software development.

Comment: Are you programming under an x86 environment?

Comment: You could avoid the assembly and do the ror in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/776523/6321114

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369405/modifying-array-elements-with-inline-assembly